# InDesign can't access TextFrames inside buttons

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have an InDesign file that contains sidebuttons like the one in the left picture, right is the document layout.

[image]
[image]

I must apply a shrink to fit to the text and do this for all the textFrames in the document

But for some reason the sidebuttons textFrames don't show up when I do  `alert(app.activeDocument.textFrames.length)`

[image]

It says 1 because I added a textFrame to see if it even works

When I move the text outside of the button and what I'm guessing is a state it would be counted.

How do I access the textFrames inside the buttons?

[Here is the file stripped to its basics](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj-Vb7GWNK0zkYpqmroTdXUCE3FZBg?e=6cwJY7)

Comment: Some text frames are not descendants of the document, rather they'll have parents who may be page, spread, group, or even story...
Speaking of stories, start with that, as these can all be found as direct descendants of a document, then find their parent keeping in mind that not all stories will belong to a text frame.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the buttons have a group inside. You can get the access to the button's textFrame this way:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var button = doc.buttons[0];

$.writeln(button.allPageItems[0].constructor.name); // Group
$.writeln(button.allPageItems[1].constructor.name); // TextFrame

var textFrame = button.allPageItems[1];
$.writeln(textFrame.contents);                      // aaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

For nested text frames (including anchored objects, frames in tables, and, of course, frames in buttons) it's probably easiest to use:

```
document.allPageItems;
```

This will give you an array (not a collection) of all page items, and you can loop through it to find the text frames:

```
if (myItems[i] instanceof TextFrame){...}
```